# How to read from dictionary that has no key in python?

Tags: python

this is a follow up from my previous question where I am working on multiple dictionary and having trouble with them. I have currently have a main dictionary where I store my data and one blank dictionary where I add data into.

```
Dairy_goods = {1:{'item':'Milk','p':2.47,'g':0.16,'offer':'Yes'},
    2:{'item':'Butter','p':4.50,'g':0.32,'offer':'No'},
    3:{'item':'Egg','p':3.40,'g':0.24,'offer':'No'}}

shopping_basket={}
```

Lets say for example I would like to add the item "Milk" into the blank shopping basket, i would do as below.

```
choose=int(input('1.Item= Milk, Price= $2.47, GST= $0.16, Offer=Yes\n'
                 '2.item= Butter, Price= $4.50, GST= $0.32, Offer=No\n'
                 '3.Item= Egg, Price= $4.50, GST= $0.32, Ofer=No\n'
                 'Enter your option: '))
qnty=int(input('How many do you want?: '))
shopping_basket[Dairy_goods[choose]['item']] = shopping_basket.get(Dairy_goods[choose]['item'], 0) + qnty,Dairy_goods[choose]['p'],Dairy_goods[choose]['g'],Dairy_goods[choose]['offer']
```

I would get an output as below.

```
print(shopping_basket)
{'Milk': (2, 2.47, 0.16, 'Yes')}
```

Now I would like to edit the values inside of this new dictionary, how do I go about doing so? As it has no fix key? I am aware it it is in a tupple and can convert to a list but will still give a error as shown below.

```
        for item in shopping_basket:
        item = str(input('key in an item to edit: '))
        for item in shopping_basket:
            shopping=list(shopping_basket) 
            qnty = int(input('Key in the quantity of %s you want: ' % item))
            shopping[item][0] = qnty # i would get a error here.
        print(shopping)
```

Let me know if more clarifications is needed, thank you in advance.

Comment: Fixed key, no, but you must have some idea of what key you *want* to use, or else how do you know which item you are modifying?

Comment: "Now I would like to edit the values inside of this new dictionary, how do I go about doing so? As it has no fix key?" I don't understand why there is a problem. You are the one responsible for the `milk` key, and the corresponding value, being there. Either there is some *rule that tells you* which key (or keys) to look for (sometimes this is "all of them"), or you have some way to *remember* which key to look for (since it will be the one you added). Otherwise, *how is it possible that you know you want to edit the dictionary at all*?

Comment: For example, in the code you showed, it appears the rule you have in mind is "ask the user for the key to look for". So... you run that code and get the key (`item = str(input('key in an item to edit: '))`)... and then use it the same way that you would use any other string (`shopping_basket[item]`). What's the difficulty? Like, I assume you wouldn't have the same question if you had two numbers in variables, and wanted to multiplying them. You wouldn't be asking how to deal with not knowing what the values are. You would just use the variables.

Comment: Why don't you just adopt the format from the product list in the shopping basket? I.e., replace `{'Milk': (2, 2.47, 0.16, 'Yes')}` with `{'Milk': {'qnty': 2, 'p': 2.47, 'g': 0.16, 'offer': 'Yes'}}`, which would make changing values straightforward? Storing the data as tuple isn't really the best choice here!

Comment: @fsimonjetz Hi! Yes that is indeed a better way to store data but may i ask how do you go about doing it? right now I am using `shopping_basket[Dairy_goods[choose]['item']] = shopping_basket.get(Dairy_goods[choose]['item'], 0) + qnty,Dairy_goods[choose]['p'],Dairy_goods[choose]['g'],Dairy_goods[choose]['offer']` as it's the only way i know, how am I able to assign the keys along with them?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things off in your code in terms of data structures. First, a dictionary with incrementing keys `{1: ..., 2: ..., ...}` is basically the same as a list, so you can just as well use the simpler data structure and select items by indexing. The only thing to note here is that list indices start at `0`, so you need to subtract `1` from your user's choice.

```py
Dairy_goods = [{'item':'Milk','p':2.47,'g':0.16,'offer':'Yes'},
               {'item':'Butter','p':4.50,'g':0.32,'offer':'No'},
               {'item':'Egg','p':3.40,'g':0.24,'offer':'No'}]


choose = int(input('1.Item = ... ')) - 1 # subtract 1 to get 0-indexing
qnty = int(input('How many do you want?: '))
```

Next up, there is *a lot* going on in the line `shopping_basket[Dairy_goods[choose]['item']] = ...`, which makes it hard to work with. In my comment, I suggested to go for dictionaries to store the items in the shopping basket to make them easier to modify. The new format of the basket would look like

```py
# shopping_basket
{'Milk':{'item':'Milk','p':2.47,'g':0.16,'offer':'Yes', 'qnty':1}}
```

which is a bit redundant because of the double item name (as key and within values), which is normally considered a bad thing, but in this case it allows for a much easier access to the shopping cart items.

However, it's actually sufficient to store **only the quantities** in the shopping basket - `{'Milk':1, 'Egg':2, ...}` - because all the other information is in `Dairy_goods`.

```py
selection = Dairy_goods[choose] # e.g., {'item':'Milk','p':2.47,'g':0.16,'offer':'Yes'}
item = selection['item'] # e.g., 'Milk'

shopping_basket[item] = shopping_basket.get(item, 0) + qnty

# optional: delete item if the quantity is <= 0
if shopping_basket[item]['qnty'] <= 0:
    shopping_basket.pop(item)
```

Then, the edit part becomes:

```py
item = input('key in an item to edit: ') # e.g., 'Milk'
qnty = int(input(f'Key in the quantity of {item} you want: ')) # did you hear about f-strings? Super useful!
shopping_basket[item] = qnty # set the new quantity
```

Answer (score 0):

I have your answer!

But first I want to address a major problem in your code:

```py
for shopItem in shopping_basket:
        item = str(input('key in an item to edit: '))
        for item in shopping_basket: # unneeded
            shopping=list(shopping_basket) 
            qnty = int(input('Key in the quantity of %s you want: ' % shopItem))
            shopping[shopItem][0] = qnty # i would get a error here.
        print(shopping)`
```

That internal for loop can be easily remove to get cleaner code.

```py
for shopItem in shopping_basket:
        item = str(input('key in an item to edit: '))
        shopping=list(shopping_basket) 
        qnty = int(input('Key in the quantity of %s you want: ' % shopItem))
        shopping[shopItem][0] = qnty # i would get a error here.
        print(shopping)`
```

Now for the actual problem:

```py
for shopItem in shopping_basket:
  item = str(input('key in an item to edit: '))
  shopping = list(shopping_basket[shopItem])
  qnty = int(input('Key in the quantity of %s you want: ' % shopItem))
  shopping[item] = qnty  # Fixed
```

Originally with this line of code
`shopping=list(shopping_basket)` you were changing `{'Milk': (2, 2.47, 0.16, 'Yes')}` to `['Milk']`, and then attempting to change a letter in the word milk, which was throwing an error. I fixed that by changing `shopping[item][0]` to `shopping[item]`.

Have a great day and good luck with your code!